# Facebook Posts lose first paragraph spacing

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Is it just my computer, or does Facebook lose the spacing between the first two paragraphs in anyone else's posts on their timeline?

It only happens between the first and second paragraphs. It seems all following paragraphs in the post are properly spaced. This has been very frustrating for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your computer or a Facebook experiment being run. This works fine for me.

In Composer
[image: Before]

After posting
[image: After]

You can always submit a help report facebook.com/help